# Object has a property that is a function, but console says it has no such method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin called [jPanelMenu](http://jpanelmenu.com/#api-on). To use it, you create a special object:

```
var jpm = jQuery.jPanelMenu();
```

and call a method of that object:

```
jpm.on();
```

So when I create the object, I can type its name and see a list of its properties, which does indeed include an 'on' property.

I can type `jpm.on` and see that this property looks like a function.

I can do `typeof jpm.on` and it returns `"function"`.

But when I call `jpm.on();`, I get

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

Here's a screenshot of me doing all the above in the console:

[image: Screenshot of the above in Chrome's JavaScript console.]

I'm not terribly keen with JavaScript, so I assume this is some gap in my basic conceptual knowledge. What is really going on here?

Comment: Hmm, try expanding the TypeError... is there a stack trace there?

Comment: It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yq36s/

Comment: Most likely the exception is thrown from within `on`. Are you using it correctly?

Comment: @cdhowie There are several things in the TypeError, as usual, but I'm not sure how to read any of it. Its properties are `arguments` `get message` `get stack` `set message` `set stack` and then `type` and `__proto__` and they all have lots of stuff inside them. If I don't get a solution in the next little bit I'll look up exactly how to read this and report back.

Comment: Maybe it's the console? Did you try doing that outside the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, guys, turns out this was just a crazy coincidence. I was running an older version of jQuery, and the `on` method it couldn't find was not the `on` I was trying to call, but rather the `on` that was added to jQuery itself in version 1.7, which apparently is used in jPanelMenu's own `on` method.

I guess the biggest clue was that in the TypeError, it said `#<Object> has no method` instead of `jpm has no method`.

Answer (score -1):

Please see that you are including your jQuery library before jPanelMenu.js

Comment: I was, but you were closer than you should've been. See my answer for the actual problem.

Comment: They already showed that `var jpm = jQuery.jPanelMenu();` works. That's pretty good evidence that jQuery is loaded

Comment: @Ian yes but it returned undefined

Comment: That's what it's supposed to return. Did you even bother testing in your console? If you declare a variable, it always returns `undefined` in the console output. That means nothing. If you look at the next line, where they just run `jpm`, it successfully displays its contents. If jQuery weren't loaded, it would've thrown an exception on `jQuery.jPanelMenu();`

Comment: @Ian yes i do agree!! My BAD!!

Comment: @arshA Haha no problem, it just would've failed a lot sooner if jQuery weren't loaded